# What is the proper name for variables in a method that acts like a property?

Tags: c#

I know this is a stupid question, but I have been teaching myself c#, so im learning the lingo as I go.

My question is: Often when I write methods, I find my self declaring objects and variables at the top of the method when I need them to share the same scope. Do these types of objects/variables have a name? I know when declared outside a method they would be properties.

Example code of what I mean: My question is what to call the objects in the Question region.

```
public Label start_Ping(String target, string name, ref bool router)
        {

       #region [ Question ] 
        Label status_Label = new Label(); //Declare the label which will be dynamically      created 

        Ping ping = new System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping(); //Declare the ping object 

        PingReply reply = null; //Declare the pingReply object      


        byte[] buffer = new byte[100]; //Set the byte size 
       #endregion 

        if (name == "router")
        {
            try
            {
                reply = ping.Send(target, 50, buffer);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
            if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                router = true;
            }
            else
            {
                router = false;
                return null;
            }
        }
try
{
...
```

Thanks in advance. I understand this may be quite simple =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `status_Label`, `ping`, `reply` and `buffer` are known simply as **local variables**.

That is, they're **local** to the method you create them in (or whatever scope you declare them in).

It doesn't matter *where* in your method you declare them, by the way, as long as they're within some scope.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me. I was working on adding some comments, and did not know if there was a proper name for them.  Thanks again!

Comment: Also if they are declared outside of the method they are called **fields**.  They are only called **properties** if they have getters and/or setters. Unless you are writing this to teach someone C# you should not use a comment or region to mark your local variables.

Comment: Or unless he's writing this to point to the specific portion of his method body in question...

Comment: I only wrote the region to point out where the question is like Bolt said..But I do appreciate the all the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

BoltClock is correct, but for future reference, variables declared outside of a method aren't properties. They're called member variables. Properties are different.

For example:

```
public class ExampleClass {
    String myString = "Hello World!";

    public String MyProperty {
        get { return myString; }
        set {
            myString = value;
            System.Console.WriteLine("MyProperty changed to " + value);
        }
    }
}
```

Here, myString is a member variable (or instance variable). It can't be accessed from outside the class.

MyProperty, as the name suggests, is a property. It's actually a kind of method that behaves like a variable, but allows other things to happen when its value is changed or accessed. In this example, setting MyProperty would output a message giving its new value.

There's some good documentation on this at MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

@BoltClock has answered your question; however, I wanted to point out that your statement, “when [variables are] declared outside a method they would be properties”, is incorrect. Variables declared outside a method are called *fields*. Properties typically have a similar purpose to fields (holding a value), but they need to be defined using `get` and `set` accessors, and can incorporate logic, such as validation or property change notification (which fields can’t).

For example:

```
public class Router
{
    private PingReply reply = null;

    public PingReply Reply
    {
        get { return reply; }
        set { reply = value; }
    }
}
```

In this case, `reply` is a field, whilst `Reply` is a property which gets or sets the value of `reply`.

Comment: I always thought that a Property was a property w/ or w/ out a get and set accessor. Thanks for pointing that out.